# Rails complaining "No such file or directory" on a file I'm asking it to create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, io

This is something I haven't seen before. I have a utility server running Sidekiq. There is a background job that creates a file like this:

```
CSV.open(filename, "wb") do |csv|
```

Here is the error:

```
No such file or directory - 52_220898_apps_import.csv
```

So why would Rails be unable to write a file to the app root from the background process? The directory is only at 9% utilization.

Comment: you have incorrect filename path should be the full path and not just a file name in filename variable

Comment: I had just figured it would go to the app root automatically. It must attempt to write to the current working directory of the calling program instead. Which explains why when I ran this from the console it worked fine, but failed when run from Sidekiq. Please put your comment in an answer so that I can reward you and close out the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sasha correctly identified above that I should have had the full pathname. Once I added that, I ceased seeing this error. I am answering this question myself to close it out. Please upvote Sasha's comment above to give credit. If Sasha ends up posting the comment as an answer I will award it.